# XPATH ancestor-or-self

Tags: oracle, xpath

Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5 - 64bi

I'm trying to output hierarhy from element, that I found, to root using **ancestor-or-self** but it doesn't work at all: just print all elements(

Well, what I have:

1) An XML file like this.

```
<Root>
  <Element1 id="UniqueId1">
    <SubElement1 id="UniqueId2"/>
    <SubElement2 id="UniqueId3">
      <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId4"/>
      <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId5"/>
    </SubElement2>
  </Element1>
  <Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
    <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
      <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/>
      <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
    </SubElement1>
  </Element2> 
</Root>
```

2) My XPATH string:

```
//*[@id and contains(@id, "UniqueId8")]/ancestor-or-self::*
```

3) I want to get the result like this (from found element to root):

```
<Root>
  <Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
    <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
      <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/>
    </SubElement1>
  </Element2> 
</Root>
```

By the way, //*[@id and contains(@id, "UniqueId8")]/ancestor-or-self::*/@id works fine.

**Does anybody know how to fix this problem or just use another operation instead of ancestor-or-self?**

UPDATE:

I just execute this:

```
DECLARE
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT xmltype('<Root>
               <Element1 id="UniqueId1">
            <SubElement1 id="UniqueId2"/>                                           <SubElement2 id="UniqueId3">
                                            <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId4"/>
                                            <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId5"/>
                                        </SubElement2>
                                    </Element1>
                                    <Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
                                        <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
                                            <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/>
                                            <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
                                        </SubElement1>
                                    </Element2>
                                </Root>')
    into v_xml
    from dual;

    select extract(v_xml, '//*[@id="UniqueId9"]/ancestor-or-self::*')
    into v_xml
    from dual;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_xml.getStringVal());

END;
```

But as a result I got something strange:

```
<Root>
  <Element1 id="UniqueId1">
              <SubElement1 id="UniqueId2"/>
            <SubElement2 id="UniqueId3">
                                     <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId4"/>
                                                 <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId5"/>
     </SubElement2>
    </Element1>
    <Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
    <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
    <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/>
    <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
    </SubElement1></Element2>
</Root>
<Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
    <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
        <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/>
        <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
    </SubElement1>
</Element2>

<SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
    <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/>
    <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
</SubElement1>

<LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guy with nick **xtender** find great solution with XPATH and it really works:

```
   with t_xml as ( select xmltype('
    <Root>
      <Element1 id="UniqueId1">
        <SubElement1 id="UniqueId2"/>
        <SubElement2 id="UniqueId3">
          <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId4"/>
          <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId5"/>
        </SubElement2>
      </Element1>
      <Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
        <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
          <LeafElement1 id2="UniqueId8"/>
          <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
        </SubElement1>
      </Element2> 
    </Root>') x from dual)
    select 
       t_xml.*
      ,updatexml(x,'//*[not (descendant-or-self::*[@id2="UniqueId8"])]',chr(10)) upd
    from t_xml
```

Answer (score 2):

XPath only allows you to select nodes in the input document, it does not allow you to change the structure of the document or create a new one with nodes being changed (added, deleted, manipulated).  Thus once you select the root element with your path expression and output the result you will of course output the root element and all nodes it contains.

So XPath can't do the job you want to do, for that you need to use XQuery or XSLT; that way you will be able to create a new document with nodes you are not interested in being removed. [Fragment input xhtml to seperate xhtml files with ancestor nodes deails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040516/fragment-input-xhtml-to-seperate-xhtml-files-with-ancestor-nodes-deails/13046672#13046672) is a sample where XSLT is used to filter out those descendant nodes of the root element that are not ancestors or children of a certain node. It does more than you need as it does so for several nodes and creates several result documents but part of the code is doing what you want. I don't know however whether you can use XSLT at all or XSLT 2.0 in the context of Oracle so I won't try to adapt that code to your input sample unless you clearly indicate you can use XSLT and which version of XSLT you can use in the context of Oracle.

Comment: I don't want to change a structure, I just need to get results like this http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=9D

Comment: Well even that page shows the complete tree, only it highlights certain nodes in it. Perhaps the answer by DazzaL helps more than my reference to XQuery or XSLT, I am not familiar with the XML data type support in Oracle.

Comment: I think you will right too about XQuery. I've got XQuery solution https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2463473&tstart=0  But I still looking for XPath solution!

Answer (score 2):

As Martin says, you can't use XPath to construct a tree that isn't present in the input.

A further point: be aware that XPath expressions select nodes. Think of it as returning a set of pointers to the nodes in the input document. It's quite common for a client environment that runs the XPath queries to display those nodes by showing the subtree rooted at the node. But the XPath expression didn't select the whole tree, it only selected the root, and the display of the subtree underneath the node might be confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this XSL approach:

```
SQL> with xml as (select xmltype('<Root>
  2    <Element1 id="UniqueId1">
  3      <SubElement1 id="UniqueId2"/>
  4      <SubElement2 id="UniqueId3">
  5        <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId4"/>
  6        <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId5"/>
  7      </SubElement2>
  8    </Element1>
  9    <Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
 10      <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
 11        <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/>
 12        <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId9"/>
 13      </SubElement1>
 14    </Element2>
 15  </Root>') xml from dual),
 16  xsl as (select xmltype('
 17  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 18   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 19   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 20    <xsl:copy>
 21     <xsl:apply-templates select="*[descendant-or-self::*[contains(@id,''UniqueId8'')]]|@*"/>
 22    </xsl:copy>
 23   </xsl:template>
 24  </xsl:stylesheet>') xsl from dual)
 25  select xm.xml.transform(xs.xsl)
 26    from xml xm, xsl xs;

XM.XML.TRANSFORM(XS.XSL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<Root>
 <Element2 id="UniqueId6" AttributeToCheck="true">
  <SubElement1 id="UniqueId7">
   <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8">
   </LeafElement1>
  </SubElement1>
 </Element2>
</Root>
```

Comment: The <LeafElement1 id="UniqueId8"/> is redundant, but it closer than my query.

Comment: Xpath is more readable for me. If you'll find XPATH solution let me know, please.

Comment: @user485553, XPath cannot modify nodes -- therefore an XPath solution isn't possible. Remember: XPath is a *query* language (only) for XML documents. It cannot create a new node or modify the structure of an existing node. For this purpose one can use XSLT.